# How to find the target variable in the dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset

I am working on the following dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xzvw-z_glMcOYxJPJ4SckuKrVOulUuzO/view?usp=sharing

My goal is to predict whether the customer would check in or not. I am having a problem finding the target variable to complete this task. There is a column named ***BookingsCheckedIn*** which I initially thought was the target variable. But on inspection, it has more than 2 unique values same goes with all the other variables (BookingsCanceled, etc.,) Now I am in a dilemma whether there is a target variable given or is there a different method to tackle this kind of problem.

Notebook I worked on: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MfwwBfi9_4E1BaZcPnS7KJjTy8xVsgZO?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like we're basically checking for a condition where `BookingsCheckedIn` > 0 to me.

Comment: so anything other than 0 is like the customer checkedin? Then would it be best to leave the var just like that or should I just change them to 1?

Comment: The goal you stated assumes binary classification. Unless it's misworded that would mean clamping this value to 0/1.

Comment: Well yes, the case study mentioned this: "Train a machine learning model (preferably with a neural network) that predicts the customer who is going to be checked in. "